# Show all results from 1st table but only 1st result from 2nd table in mySql join statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form which searches for firstname, lastname, address (and several other columns which I have left out here for simplicity) in the following tables:

MEMBERS

```
id | firstname | lastname
---+-----------+-----------
1  | Jon       | Doe
2  | Mary      | Smith
3  | Jon       | James
```

ADDRESSES

```
id | member_id | address
---+-----------+-----------
1  | 1         | Home address
2  | 1         | Work address
3  | 2         | Home address
4  | 3         | Home address
5  | 3         | Work address
6  | 3         | Holiday address
```

A member can have an unlimited number of addresses.

How do I search for all occurences of 'Jon' as firstname but only display the first address? For example:

```
Jon Doe Home address
Jon James Home address
```

This is our mySQL statement so far:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_members T1 INNER JOIN tbl_addresses T2 ON T1.id = T2.member_id WHERE firstname = 'Jon'
```

We have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_members T1 LEFT JOIN tbl_addresses T2 ON T1.id = T2.member_id WHERE firstname = 'Jon'
```

Both these statements give us:

```
Joh Doe Home address 
Jon Doe Work address 
Jon James Home address 
Jon James Work address 
Jon James Holiday address
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you should do something like this:

```
SELECT T1.firstname, T1.lastname, T2.address
FROM MEMBERS AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT member_id, address
            FROM ADDRESSES
            GROUP BY member_id) AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.member_id
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb376/2) for that to see how it's work...

GL!

**EDIT:**

Of course if you need you can add WHERE clause at the end of query to select specific name from table or group of name like

```
WHERE firstname = 'joe'
```

or whatsoever...

[Hire is a Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb376/3) for that...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIMIT` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_members T1 INNER JOIN tbl_addresses T2 ON T1.id = T2.member_id WHERE firstname = 'Jon' LIMIT 1
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need to show the first address for Jon Doe AND the first address for Jon James: 'How do I search for all occurences of 'Jon' as firstname but only display the first address?'

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `GROUP BY` clause to your SQL statement

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, address
FROM members
JOIN addresses ON members.id = addresses.member_id
WHERE firstname = 'Jon'
GROUP BY members.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the keyword **LIMIT**, as described [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx).

Using `LIMIT 1`, you'll limit your query to the first row returned.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to show the first address for Jon Doe AND the first address for Jon James: 'How do I search for all occurences of 'Jon' as firstname but only display the first address?'